# ERROR typing HTML in templates folder in flask framework

Tags: python, html, flask

I typed '`!`' in HTML file in templates folder but it prevents me from continuing the code automatically
So that, I can't make a template to my web page with flask till now.
See the image I attached to understand more clearly, and if anything doesn't clear, please till me. And thank you for you efforts

- I tried to type `<!DOCTYPE html>`, but it didn't work.
- And I also tried to change the folder name from 'templates' to 'template' it works in typing the html code but still empty page
- I re-installed flask and vs code, there is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

When html doc in templates, the typing `<!DOCTYPE html>` is not working. I found the solution by myself **which is to move your html doc to the outside of templates and put the same location with your main.py.** Then u can edit your html easily. I'm not sure if there is any other solution for that.After edit your HTML you can put into templates again.

Comment: Yes, I also found that, but still empty page doesn't change...And I used to write it normally...So, what's wrong now?